# How to allow only one instance of UWP App?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am having a scenario where I don't want to allow the user to open more than one instance in windows 10 app if app instance already running. Can we restrict this from the app code side? Anyone have an idea please share that will help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369720/how-to-restrict-a-program-to-a-single-instance try reading this

Answer (score 2):

> How to allow only one instance of UWP App?

The default model of UWP app is single instance, and we can't change it with code. if you want it multiple instance, you need edit in the package  `appxmanifest` for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/multi-instance-uwp).