# Cross-process mutex instantiation

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, mutex

Just wrote a simple program that must be processed once at a time, so achieved this by using a keyed `Mutex` with a particular name.
The code (simplified) looks like this.

```
static readonly string APP_NAME = "MutexSample";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mutex mutex;
    try
    {
        mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(APP_NAME);
        // At this point, with no exception,
        // the Mutex is acquired, so there is another
        // process running
        // Environment.Exit(1); or something
    }
    catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
    {
        // If we could not acquire any mutex with
        // our app name, let's create one
        mutex = new Mutex(true, APP_NAME);
    }

    Console.ReadKey(); // Just for keeping the application up
    // At some point, I just want to release
    // the mutex
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

My first attempt was instantiating the `Mutex` like `new Mutex(false, APP_NAME)`, but calling `mutex.ReleaseMutex()` was throwing an exception

> `System.ApplicationException: 'Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.'`

Just noticed that the first parameter of the constructor (`initiallyOwned`) marks whether the current thread that is creating the `Mutex` owns it and, unsurprisingly, a thread cannot release a `Mutex` which is not owned by that thread.

So changing this parameter to `true` fixed that issue, as shown on the code above.

Well, my question is, what is the whole point of that parameter? I mean, when will I need to create a `Mutex` that I am not able to release it.
And, if I set the parameter `initiallyOwned` to `false`, who does really own that `Mutex`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody owns a `Mutex`, unless it's acquired by somebody by calling its method [`WaitOne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone). Passing `initiallyOwned: true` is an attempt to acquire immediately a newly created `Mutex`, but it's problematic. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor#System_Threading_Mutex__ctor_System_Boolean_System_String_):

> You should not use this constructor to request initial ownership, unless you can be certain that the thread will create the named mutex.

There is also [an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor#System_Threading_Mutex__ctor_System_Boolean_System_String_System_Boolean__) that accepts three parameters:

```
public Mutex (bool initiallyOwned, string name, out bool createdNew);
```

...but it's simpler to just create the `Mutex` without initial ownership, and later acquire it when you are ready to be blocked (in case it happens to be acquired by someone else).

```
mutex = new Mutex(initiallyOwned: false, APP_NAME);
mutex.WaitOne(); // Potentially blocking
```

Comment: Well, may be a smarter way to do the same would be actually create the `Mutex` and then try to `WaitOne` and peek into the `boolean` result?

Comment: @VRoxa yeap, calling `WaitOne` with a zero value for the `millisecondsTimeout` argument is certainly a flexible option!

Comment: Just for the sake of completion. In response of the documentation quote... At the point I am creating the `Mutex` on my first example above, I am completely sure I can create the named `Mutex`, ain't I? So, that would fit in my context.

Comment: I think that your code has a race condition between the lines `mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(APP_NAME)` and `mutex = new Mutex(true, APP_NAME)`. Another process could create and acquire the ownership of the mutex in the meanwhile. The chances are small, but I would definitely not feel comfortable having this code running in the production environment.

Answer (score 1):

> when will I need to create a `Mutex` that I am not able to release it.

That's really too broad a question. But a less broad question would be:

> How could I release a `Mutex` that wasn't initially owned when I create it?

And the answer to that is easy: just acquire the `Mutex` *after* you create it. Then you can release it.

> And, if I set the parameter `initiallyOwned` to false, who does really own that Mutex?

That depends on whether the `Mutex` was already created and acquired by some other thread or process. If it wasn't, then *no one* owns it and your code would be able to acquire it later.

Of course, for the scenario you're dealing with, you don't necessarily even want to acquire the `Mutex`. The usual approach is to try to *create* the `Mutex` with [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Mutex__ctor_System_Boolean_System_String_System_Boolean__). The third parameter will be set if your code actually created the `Mutex`. You never actually need to acquire it; you're just using the fact that the OS will ensure that the `Mutex` is only ever created once.

Note that there is already a lot of really good advice about writing single-instance programs with .NET. I strongly recommend you review the information found here:
[What is the correct way to create a single-instance WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19147)
[How to restrict a program to a single instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4369720)